Problems with prlctl exec in zsh using Parallels, permission denied: NUL
In this stack overflow answer there is a solution that almost works for me.
I have a Windows virtual machine running on top of Parallels on a Mac.
I want to write a python scripts that run on the Mac's OS-X UNIX-like environment, which invoke a Windows app on Parallels. I'm trying to make sure the code executes from terminal before putting it in python.

The only problem is after executing
prlctl exec myProgram.exe argument1>NUL </dev/null & MyFileThatIRun.txt
I get the following error: zsh: permission denied: NUL
I've tried nul, NUL, I've tried running with out the NUL.
I'm not really 100% understanding the nul I just know its gotten me further.
Does anyone have insight on how to fix zsh: permission denied: NUL?
I tried a verity of permutations of the command line:
prlctl exec myProgram.exe --guest-os-type windows argument1> NUL </dev/null & MyFile
prlctl exec myProgram.exe --guest-os-type windows argument1> NUL </dev/null MyFile
prlctl exec myProgram.exe argument1> NUL </dev/null & MyFile
prlctl exec myProgram.exe argument1> NUL </dev/null MyFile 
prlctl exec myProgram.exe argument1> NUL < /dev/null & MyFile 
prlctl exec myProgram.exe argument1> NUL < /dev/null MyFile 
prlctl exec myProgram.exe argument1> NUL & MyFile 
prlctl exec myProgram.exe argument1 >NUL & MyFile

I was expecting the myProgram to launch and run the MyFile.

Can you try running that code in bash instead of zsh?

Presumably your current working directory is one you don't have permission to create files in.

Thanks for responding.  @Shawn your are correct permissions is part of the problem however fixing permissions was not my only problem.   There was a lot of misunderstanding on my part, obviously or I wouldn't have a problem.  I didn't not fully understand the documentation and there was several compounding issues.  I need to pass the VM name after exec.  In addition to this the default user was not who I expected to be, some kind of nt windows system user thing resulting in me not having as much permissions as I was expecting.   the error in accessing NULL was a bit of a red fish.

From documentations: Parallels pdf doc or parallels html doc
prlctl exec <vm_id | vm_name> <command>

So my above command was missing the vm name.  I think the default case looks like the following
prlctl exec "Windows 11" "C:\path\to\myProgram.exe" "X:path\to\MyFile.txt"

However this was not quite working as expected because the program could not find myFile.txt. The problem is the user was not me so to correct that issue I use the following command
prlctl exec --current-user "Windows 11" "C:\path\to\myProgram.exe" "X:path\to\MyFile.txt"

Alterntivlty you can use
prlctl exec --user <user_name> --password <password> "Windows 11" "C:\path\to\myProgram.exe"

in order to discover all this I use the intercavie command that allows me to dynamically interact with cmd prompt via terminal.
prlctl enter "Windows 11"
whoami


nt authority\system

This was not the user I expected and realized I did not have access to the mounted drives I expected with that system. I discovered this by doing the following while tunneled/login to the parallels VM cmd prompt
wmic logicaldisk get caption

After correcting the vm name and the user name the command executes mostly correctly.  I still have permissions issues but the program can find the myfile.txt now. I believe my current permissions issues have nothing to do with the above.
